# Error while calculating metrics like AUC, ACC in R

Tags: r, cart

I am trying to make predictions on my validation data using a decision tree model created with training data set. I am able to do that with success but, I am not able to calculate various metrics like Area under curve (AUC), and overall classification rate (ACC) using mmetric() command in R. 
Here is the screen shot with errors and commands that I used.
Note: Right click the image and select view image to see it clearly.
"t" is my training data set and "v" is validation data set.
[image: mmetric]

Note: You can download my training data set "t" and validation data set "v" as a .csv files from here: [Click here](http://tinyurl.com/cla44km)
I used the same commands for a different data set and it worked perfectly, so could be this due to some problem with my data set.

Thanks,

P

Comment: what's `dim(v)`? Does `v` contain any missing data?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.  You can create a toy dataset, or use one of the ones built into R (e.g. iris).

Comment: @JonathanChristensen, I have updated the question as per ur needs.

Regards,

Comment: @Zach this error is not reproducible for dataset that are in R-tool.(I mentioned that above!) this command works fine for iris data set.
Regards

Comment: @pss surely you can create another dataset with the same problem.  I can't see where you code is wrong if I can't run it line by line.  In fact, the very act of creating a dataset that reproduces your error will likely inform you what the problem is.

Comment: @Zach, these data sets "t", "v" are basically created from other data sets"train", "valid" respectively that were created from a big data set "alldata" by using holdout command. Now when I see contents of "train"(training data set) using head(), I see observations are random, eg: category is 1,3,6,4,2,8,5,9... but when I see content of "valid"(validation data) I see the observations are in sequence number eg: category is 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3.... Could this be the cause of problem? Regards,

Comment: @pss In general, when posting a question like this (request for help with an error) it's good to `dput` a sample of the dataset, and include the exact commands, as text, that reproduce the problem.  That way someone can copy/paste your code straight out of the site, and get the same error.  Posting an image is basically useless.

Comment: @Zach question is updated according to your recommendations. Regards

Comment: @pss you may want to try to fix your question

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are having technical issues editing your questions or whether you are purposefully vandalizing them. If the latter, *please* stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `predict()` to return classes and not probabilities:

```
vpredict=predict(tree,t,type="class")
```

The default for classification with `predict.rpart()` is to return a matrix with probabilities of each class.  However, mmetric wants the classes.

(I also think people are having / have had difficulty helping because you did not include your data or information on the libraries your commands came from and you used a screenshot rather than text that people could copy and paste. Help us to help you! :-) )

Comment: First of all thank you very much!!!
I shall keep your suggestion in mind while I post next time. The size of my data is so big that it would make my question a messed up crap if I pasted my data here thats why I didn't do that. 
Regards and have a nice weekend!!!

Comment: I have a request for you. Can you please have a look at my other questions here: http://tinyurl.com/clu6bve,  http://tinyurl.com/d3m57vc. Thanks.